# How to pass option set as parameter for scrollpositions?

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, scroll-position

I want to pass option set for scroll position as parameter argument, but facing some issue.

Please can anyone write how to do it?

```
func selectCurrentWallpaperCell() { //want to pass parameter here
        let currentWallpaperID = self.wallpaperManager.currentWallpaperID
        if let index = self.wallpapers.index(where: { $0.id == currentWallpaperID }) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
            self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition()) // how to use in scrollposition?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let options: UICollectionViewScrollPosition = [.top, .centeredVertically]
self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: options)
```

Reference: [OptionSet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset)

Answer (score 0):

[UICollectionViewScrollPosition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewscrollposition) conforms to [OptionSet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset) protocol and hence you can pass two or more options like Suhit has already answered.
You just need to make your function accept `UICollectionViewScrollPosition` as an argument and pass that as parameter to collectionview's `selectItem`: method.